# how can I send request as multipart/form-data from ZUL to Composer in ZK?

Tags: httprequest, zk, zul

My problem is i want to upload a file through ZK native HTML.
But in composer when I try to get file from request object it says form type is not multipart/form-data.

## Can anyone suggest me how can I change the request type in **ZK**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to make the fileupload work with IE11 without updating zk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346765/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-the-fileupload-work-with-ie11-without-updating-zk)

Comment: that quest was different.